# Put closure inside a union

Tags: rust, closures, parser-combinators

I'm trying to implement a parser combinator in rust.

I have the following parser, which is built with no errors/warnings:

```rust
use std::char;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ParseResult<T> {
    Success(T),
    Failure(&'static str),
}

fn pchar(char_to_match: char) -> impl Fn(&str) -> ParseResult<(&str, &str)> {
    move |string: &str| match string.get(0..1) {
        Some(found) => match found.chars().next().unwrap() == char_to_match {
            true => ParseResult::Success((found, string.get(1..).unwrap())),
            false => ParseResult::Failure("char didnt match"),
        },
        None => ParseResult::Failure("No more left to parse."),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", ParseResult::Success(&3));
    println!("{:?}", pchar('s')("r"));
    println!("{:?}", (|(a, b)| (a, b))((2, 3)));
    let input_abc = "ABC";
    println!("{:?}", pchar('A')(input_abc));
```

Instead of returning a function (closure) from `pchar`, I want to return a `Parser<T>` which I have declared as:

```rust
union Parser<T> {
    func: dyn Fn(&str) -> ParseResult<(T, &str)>,
}
```

Then my second iteration of pchar can return a `Parser<T>` such as:

```rust
fn pchar2(char_to_match: char) -> Parser<&str> {
    Parser {
        func: |string: &str| match string.get(0..1) {
            Some(found) => match found.chars().next().unwrap() == char_to_match {
                true => ParseResult::Success((found, string.get(1..).unwrap())),
                false => ParseResult::Failure("char didnt match"),
            },
            None => ParseResult::Failure("No more left to parse."),
        },
    }
}
```

I get all sorts of warnings regarding lifetime parameters, size at compile-time and expected trait dyn Fn.

What do I need to learn to solve this issue?

**Update**:
As per [Aleksander Krauze's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13078067/aleksander-krauze) suggestion, I have updated it to use a `Box`.

```rust
struct Parser<T> {
    func: Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> ParseResult<(T, &str)>>,
}

fn pchar2(char_to_match: char) -> Parser<&'static str> {
    Parser {
        func: Box::new(move |string: &str| match string.get(0..1) {
            Some(found) => match found.chars().next().unwrap() == char_to_match {
                true => ParseResult::Success((found, string.get(1..).unwrap())),
                false => ParseResult::Failure("char didnt match"),
            },
            None => ParseResult::Failure("No more left to parse."),
        }),
    }
}
```

The error I get is that the lifetime of the variable `string` must outlive `char_to_match`.

**Update 2**:
As per [Aleksander Krauze's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13078067/aleksander-krauze) answer. Here is the final working version:

```rust
fn pchar2<'a>(char_to_match: char) -> Parser<'a, &'a str> {
    Parser {
        func: Box::new(move |string: &'a str| match string.char_indices().next() {
            Some((i, c)) => match c == char_to_match {
                true => ParseResult::Success((
                    string.get(..i + 1).unwrap(),
                    string.get(i + 1..).unwrap(),
                )),
                false => ParseResult::Failure("char didnt match"),
            },
            None => ParseResult::Failure("No more left to parse."),
        }),
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you cannot use bare `dyn` types. They must be behind some kind of a reference. The easiest to do is `Box` them. So you could change your `func` filed to be `Box<dyn ...>`.

Comment: I have updated the question to include your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet should fix your lifetime errors. The main problem was that you tried to return `&'static str`, when it was only a subslice of `string`. Types here are a little complex, but you could try to simplify them if `Parser` wouldn't be generic over `T` (but have `T = &'a str`). I don't know however what is your more general usecase, so it might not be viable.

**Note that even that this code compiles, it has a bug!** In rust strings are UTF-8 encoded, so single character can take anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes. But when you slice `&str` you are giving bytes indexes. That could result in a panic at runtime if you would slice in the middle of a character.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum ParseResult<T> {
    Success(T),
    Failure(&'static str),
}

struct Parser<'a, T> {
    func: Box<dyn Fn(&'a str) -> ParseResult<(T, &'a str)>>,
}

fn pchar2<'a>(char_to_match: char) -> Parser<'a, &'a str> {
    Parser {
        func: Box::new(move |string: &'a str| match string.get(0..1) {
            Some(found) => match found.chars().next().unwrap() == char_to_match {
                true => ParseResult::Success((found, string.get(1..).unwrap())),
                false => ParseResult::Failure("char didnt match"),
            },
            None => ParseResult::Failure("No more left to parse."),
        }),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have gotten your version to work. I'm such a beginner that `'a` syntax is new to me, so I will read up on that. I need to make Parser generic on any type, as it would be containing a parse tree in the future, so I will work on integrating that.

Comment: @SimonSolnes Good luck. Don't forget to fix that bug I pointed out.

Comment: Haha I totally forgot. I see slicing is not chars, but bytes. It also seems like your answer is completely generic on what ever I need to store there.